# I want to return images in flatlist from an array that contians links/urls for images react-native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image, react-native

I want to return images  in flatlists .
first of all this array qwer[]  contains url links the images init
it evens console.logs it gets the links from an api .
i have manually tried putting images in View tag with the source  and it works .
but when i do with with flatlists it shows no  error but doesnot display images .
Can u help me please ?

```
return(
    <FlatList 
    horizontal
    showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
    data={qwer}
    renderItem={({ item }) => (
        <Image 
            source={({uri:item})}
            style={{
                width:260,
                height:300,
                borderWidth:2,
                borderColor:'#d35647',
                resizeMode:'contain',
                margin:8
            }}
        />
    )}
/>
```

Comment: Can you update question to include as much of the component code as possible so that we may see how `qwer` is instantiated and updated/used thoughout the component?

Comment: [https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/meme-gallery-f2090.appspot.com/o/memes%2F4311037bfe305c678129463dc3016d66.jpg?alt=media&token=b2082f98-6795-4def-9877-862146ae66fe]  this is the link they output

Comment: Seems to work in an [expo snack](https://snack.expo.io/@drew.w.reese/mad-milkshake) for iOS, android, and web.

Comment: Try adding keyExtractor prop in Flatlist

Answer (score 0):

In your code just replace

```
 source={({uri:item})}
```

to

```
source={{uri : item}}
```